# .net MAUI can't see iOS methods and properties because it's state as disabled

Tags: .net, maui, .net-maui.shell

I've recently integrated xamarin forms project to .net maui. I can see android custom define methods but in iOS it's showing as disable.

P.S: It's working properly but i didn't get any suggestion for iOS.

[image]

I've target iOS version as well.

.CsProj

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
<!--         Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
         <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> 
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>MobileApp</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>Test</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.test.demo</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>65aa90ec-865a-4ee8-9d89-2f66fc2438e8</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <Configurations>Release;Debug</Configurations>
        <UserSecretsId>1cde96b1-590c-4af8-a8a8-b6de3c7a3c67</UserSecretsId>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

can someone help me with this ??

Comment: Assuming you're using Visual Studio, what configuration have you selected in the dropdown just below the file tab titles? My guess is that you've got an Android configuration selected - change to an iOS configuration, and the Android part will be grayed-out, and the iOS part will come to life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Platform code can be invoked from cross-platform code by using conditional compilation, or by using partial classes and partial methods.

You can choose the platform to make the code bright like this:

[image]